# Where is keycloak starter for Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I'd need to use keycloak in my Spring Boot project. I can see from the many tutorials that it should be available in the Spring Boot Initializr:
[image]
However I cannot find it (anymore?) neither with the Cloud app, nor with "spring init". Has it been removed as starter?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it has been removed, see [this issue for more details](https://github.com/spring-io/start.spring.io/issues/48). In general going to https://github.com/spring-io/start.spring.io and searching in issues could be an effective way to get some information about the evolution of the service in general.